# Object html headers for CloudFront with S3 backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I stumbled upon this AWS blog while doing some research about adding HTML headers to S3 objects served via CF:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/adding-http-security-headers-using-lambdaedge-and-amazon-cloudfront/

Apparently, we can create lambda@edge to update headers of all objects before it reaches CF cache. But, I have been doing something similar where I update S3 object metadata with headers, something like:

```
aws s3 cp --content-type 'text/html' --cache-control 'no-cache' s3://my_bucket/index.html s3://my_bucket/index.html --metadata-directive REPLACE
```

This basically copy and paste the same object to add HTTP headers to my specified objects without using lambda to modify in-flight.

So is there any difference between hardcoding headers to S3 objects and using lambda@edge to modify origin response?

Answer (score 0):

It is just easier to use the Lambda @Edge to have one central place where you can maintain the headers. For example you can set your caching headers as well as your security headers in the Lambda @Edge and if you have to add or change it you just need to update the Lambda, give it a new version and deploy it to Cloud Front.

Comment: But with Lambda you have another component to create and maintain. Running a command seems easier for me

Comment: Casper - I think it depends on your setup. If you have only a few buckets and you can run the same command or a few commands that set the headers it is OK. If you have many S3 buckets with many distributions and maybe you want to apply specific headers to specific types of files then the @Edge function works well to centrally control it. I do not think there is a right or a wrong answer, depends what works for you.